# Can I use scattergl with ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I want to create a plot with a lasso selection in a shiny app. However, even with only 1000 points the respond times are unbearable. I have read that one can improve the responsiveness using scattergl, but I do not find any option to do that with ggplotly. Thats a shame, since I would like to use my already constructed ggplot.

Here some code to reproduce:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

N <- 10e3

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("p"),
  plotlyOutput("p10"),
  plotlyOutput("p100"),
  plotlyOutput("p2"),
  plotlyOutput("p3"),
  plotlyOutput("p3_"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$p100 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type="scattergl",mode="markers", x=rnorm(100*N), y=rnorm(100*N))
  })
  output$p10 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type="scattergl",mode="markers", x=rnorm(10*N), y=rnorm(10*N))
  })
  output$p <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type="scattergl",mode="markers", x=rnorm(N), y=rnorm(N))
  })
  output$p2 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type="scatter",mode="markers", x=rnorm(N), y=rnorm(N))
  })
  output$p3 <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(N), y=rnorm(N)))+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)))
  })
  output$p3_ <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(N), y=rnorm(N)))+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)), type="scattergl")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser=TRUE))
```

The responsiveness for p, p10 and p100 is somewhat OK, for the others it is not. The `type="scattergl"` seems not to change anything, as far as I can tell.

More over I get the output

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4932
Warning: 'scattergl' trace types don't currently render in RStudio on Windows. Open in another web browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc).
Warning: 'scattergl' trace types don't currently render in RStudio on Windows. Open in another web browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc).
Warning: 'scattergl' trace types don't currently render in RStudio on Windows. Open in another web browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc).
Warning: 'scattergl' trace types don't currently render in RStudio on Windows. Open in another web browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc).
Warning: 'scattergl' trace types don't currently render in RStudio on Windows. Open in another web browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc).
Warning: 'scattergl' trace types don't currently render in RStudio on Windows. Open in another web browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc).
```

I find this strange, I opened the shiny app in Firefox, and it is also displaying fine, so I do not understand why I get this warning.

So to summarize my question: Is there a way to make the performance of ggplotly somewhat OK?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `toWebGL(ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(N), y=rnorm(N)))+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)))` does the trick.

The only downside is that I get a ton of warnings that are difficult to mute. I will look into that.